# Wrap GWT Widget into SmartGWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'm using SmartGWT TabSet and want to display in a Tab a Widget from an other project which was developed with GWT.

In short:

I want to add a `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget` to a `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tab.Tab`.

`setPane()` however takes only a Canvas.

Is there a way to tie in the GWT developed Widget into a SmartGWT tab?

What I tried was to convert the Widget into a Canvas such as:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.addChild(w);
tab.setPane(c);
```

However this throws following exception:

```
Uncaught JavaScript exception [uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.AssertionError: A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list] in
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use one of the subclasses of Canvas to be your layout for the individual tab.  Something using [Layout and addMember(Widget)](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/layout/Layout.html#addMember%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29) maybe.

```
Layout layout = new VStack();
layout.addMember(w);
tab.setPane(layout);
```

Take a look at [VStack](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/layout/VStack.html) and/or [DynamicForm](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html) for some ideas.  You can also view code in [the showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_tabs_custom_controls).

Good luck.

Comment: No - that does not work - tried around for a while various combinations

It seems that there is some trouble embedding GWT components into SmartGWT Tabs. I even downloaded the nightlybuild of SmartGWT.

Comment: Funny - I actually figured out how to get rid of the problem which is really strange (guess due to lack of understanding).

I just removed: 

`RootPanel.get().add( xx );`

Comment: I didn't see that in your code.  Where is RootPanel.get().add()?  Were you using that to add the widget?  If so then it was being added twice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: http://code.google.com/p/uibinding-smartgwt/